# How to do two bar graph with a line chart in it in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I got four columns "Hour", "Average Requests", "Weekday FTE" and "Difference in Demand Weekday".

[image]

and i want the resulting graph should be like this

[image]

I got the same template in excel but I need it in tableau. Any solution in tableau would be big help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried dual axis in tableau and everything but I couldnt get that template in tableau

Comment: Can you link a sample workbook?

Comment: How to add the sample workbook?

Comment: Use a third party (dropbox, google drive, etc).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FvJIUsXalexf1fhdaMAKAaXYGVhgxeEl/view?usp=sharing   here u go

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FvJIUsXalexf1fhdaMAKAaXYGVhgxeEl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to save it as a packaged workbook so it saves the data with it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gUgSZ6xtc7KT9wP-0aKYEGMA0oETBsmS/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Due to having multiple measures as the bars, the line portion would not be continuous as desired. I used a transparent sheet trick on a dashboard. So I layered the line chart on top of the bars. https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfq51wu2tpmsfaw/200102%20stack%20question.twbx?dl=0

https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2018/11/express-your-data-artistry-transparent-worksheets-tableau-98807

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a combination chart. The following link details the steps involved in creating one:

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/qs_combo_charts.htm

Once you understand the basic concept, you can add as many measures into the chart as you want. Hope this helps.

Edit:

Adding a video link which shows multiple bar and line charts added in the same chart.

https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/creating-a-graph-that-combines-a-bar-chart-with-two-or-more-lines

Comment: Thank You for the link. Yeah its easy to plot two different measures but when it comes to three measures thats where things are getting super complicated.

Comment: Added a video link with three measures added. Hope it works for you.